# Hazelcast entry doesnt get expired on ttl

Tags: hazelcast-imap

I have multi node(two members) in cluster and I am using Hazelcast for caching data. When I put the entry in IMap map.putIfAbsent(id.toString(), idMap, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES); it is expected that the entry should get expired in 15 minutes.

hazelcastInstance.getMap("ID").addEntryListener(listener, true);

But this doesnt happen and the expirylistener gets fired randomly. What could be the cause of the issue and how to resolve it.